# SQLAlchemy Unique Object pattern

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In the past I worked on a project that included a version of the [Unique Object](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/UniqueObject) pattern. That particular code was not written by me and looking for some information I found the original recipe. I'm trying to understand it, but some details scape to my mind.

The implementation that was done in the project is quite similar to the one provided in the wiki, but instead of `_unique`, `get_unique` is implemented as a classmethod of a common base model. It accepts arbitrary parameters and does almost what `_unique` does in the wiki, but having decided about the `hashfunc`, `queryfunc` and `constructor` parameters:

```
class Model(Base):
    @classmethod
    def get_unique(cls, session, **kwargs):
        """Get or create an instance based on unique values.
        """
        cache = getattr(session, '_unique_cache', None)
        if cache is None:
            session._unique_cache = cache = {}

        key = (cls, tuple(kwargs.items()))
        o = cache.get(key)

        if o is not None and was_deleted(o):
            o = None

        if o is None:
            with session.no_autoflush:
                o = session.query(cls).filter_by(**kwargs).first()

            if o is None:
                o = cls(**kwargs)
                session.add(o)

            cache[key] = o

        return o
```

I am aware of some caveats of this implementation, being one of the most important the fact that the order of kwargs matters for the construction of `key`. My questions:

1. Is there any reason to enclose the query in a `no_autoflush`context? What would be wrong if the programmer cloud decide whether `get_unique`is called with or without `autoflush`? The wiki recipe also performs the query with `no_autoflush` and I wonder if something is escaping my understanding.
2. Why are the objects cached? I don't see the point of caching the objects when session already performs a similar task and is aware of when it has to re-retrieve the objects from the database.
3. Is therefore something wrong with the following implementation that does not use the cache and lets the programmer to decide whether a `no_autoflush` context is required?

```
class Model(Base):
    @classmethod
    def get_unique(cls, session, **kwargs):
        """Get or create an instance based on unique values.
        """
        o = session.query(cls).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
        if o is None:
            o = cls(**kwargs)
            session.add(o)
        return o
```